# C++ http program returns 505 HTTP Version Not Supported error

Tags: c++, http, c++11, visual-c++, https

I'm trying to get public ip address of my sysetm using windows C++ api. But, I got following response:

```
HTTP/1.1 505 HTTP Version Not Supported
Connection: close
Server: Cowboy
Date: Sat, 29 Sep 2018 08:46:51 GMT
Content-Length: 0
```

**My Code:**

```
std::stringstream request2;
std::string hostName = "api.ipify.org";
std::string path = "/?format=text";

request2 << "GET " << path <<" HTTP/1.1" << std::endl;
request2 << "Host: " << hostName << std::endl;

request2 << std::endl;
std::string request1 = request2.str();

//init winsock
if (WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 0), &wsaData) != 0)
{
    exit(1);
}

//open socket
if ((sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP)) < 0)
{
    exit(1);
}

struct hostent  *he;
memset(&serveraddr, 0, sizeof(serveraddr));

const char *hostname = hostName.c_str();
if ((he = gethostbyname(hostname)) == NULL)
{
    WriteLogFile("Host not found");
    exit(1);
}

/* copy the network address to sockaddr_in structure */
memcpy(&serveraddr.sin_addr, he->h_addr_list[0], he->h_length);
serveraddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
serveraddr.sin_port = htons(PORT);

if ((connect(sock, (struct sockaddr *) &serveraddr, sizeof(serveraddr))) < 0)
{
    exit(1);
}

//send request
if (send(sock, request1.c_str(), request1.length(), 0) != request1.length())
{
    exit(1);
}

//get response
response = "";
resLen = BUFFERSIZE;
while (resLen == BUFFERSIZE)
{
    resLen = recv(sock, (char*)&buffer, BUFFERSIZE, 0);
    if (resLen>0) {
        response += std::string(buffer).substr(0, resLen);
    }
}

IpAddress = response;

//disconnect
closesocket(sock);

//cleanup
WSACleanup();
```

Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Note: My request link:

```
https://api.ipify.org/?format=text
```

Comment: Most likely unrelated to your problem, but don't forget that the line-ending in HTTP is the `"\r\n"` combination, it's not guaranteed that `std::endl` adds that. Add the newline sequence explicitly, and skip the use of `std::endl` (which does things that isn't needed here as well).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I tried but now return 0.

Comment: Have you tried to read the return value of the send() function? It can be less than the number of bytes you want to send, or equal to SOCKET_ERROR: [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winsock2/nf-winsock2-send)

Comment: As @Someprogrammerdude suggested,replace all `std::endl` to `"\r\n"`.i've tried,it worked.

Answer (score 0):

You say

> Note: My request link:
>   `https://api.ipify.org/?format=text`

But it is not possible to connect to an **https** server with a plain socket like that. You'd need something like OpenSSL. However, if you change the link to

`http://api.ipify.org/?format=text`

(Note the *http*, without an *S*, instead of *https*.)

... that *should* work.